# How to handle missing values by including all types of filling in one function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, missing-data

I make a naive function to **handle the missing values**, but unfortunately, the function didn't work.

Here is the example I have tried:

```
#Basic libraries
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def handle_missing(df,list_columns,handle_type,value):
       
    if handle_type == "bfill":
        df = df.loc[:,list_columns].fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)
                                
    elif handle_type == "ffill":
        df = df.loc[:,list_columns].fillna(method='bfill')
        
    elif handle_type == "mean":
        df = df[list_columns].fillna(df.mean()).round(2)
        
    elif handle_type == "dropna0":
        df = df[list_columns].dropna(axis=0, how='any')
    
    elif handle_type == "dropna1":
        df = df[list_columns].dropna(axis=1, how='any')
        
    else:
        df = df.loc[:,list_columns].fillna(value)

data_dict = {'First':[100, 90, np.nan, 95], 
        'Second': [30, 45, 56, np.nan], 
        'Third':[np.nan, 40, 80, 98]} 
  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
list_columns = ['First','Second','Third']
df1 = handle_missing(df1,list_columns,"bfill",0)
df1
```

Is there are any issues with this function that I have to take into concentration?

If this function isn't recommended, please suggest to me a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function looks fine, except that it returns `None`, so your `df1` is actually `None`. I would rewrite the function like this:

```
def handle_missing(df,list_columns,handle_type,value):
       
    if handle_type == "bfill":
        # no inplace
        df[list_columns] = df[list_columns].fillna(method='bfill')
                                
    elif handle_type == "ffill":
        df[list_columns] = df.loc[:,list_columns].fillna(method='bfill')
        
    elif handle_type == "mean":
        df[list_columns] = df[list_columns].fillna(df.mean()).round(2)
        
    elif handle_type == "dropna0":
        df[list_columns] = df[list_columns].dropna(axis=0, how='any')
    
    elif handle_type == "dropna1":
        df[list_columns] = df[list_columns].dropna(axis=1, how='any')
        
    else: 
        df[list_columns] = df.loc[:,list_columns].fillna(value)
```

Now the function will modify the dataframe **inplace**. So you just need:

```
handle_missing(df1,['Third'],"bfill",999)
print(df1)
```

Comment: I followed your advice and used the function that you have suggested, but when I used this command, it doesn't work properly, and all columns were deleted except column 'Third'.
`df1 = handle_missing(df1,['Third'],"",999)
`
Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Isn't that how your function supposed to be? Or do you mean you just want to fill nan for the columns in `list_columns`? If so see the updated answer.

Comment: I need the function to fill the Nan values for a particular data frame and a list of columns. the first time when I think it worked correctly, I've inserted the all columns. But, the result is different when I add one column.

Comment: @QaddomiObaid the modified function should work as expected now. But **do not** reassign.

Comment: I appreciate your help. :) 
Thanks a lot. I will test it now.